# Select-Object changes selected value

Tags: windows, powershell

Short problem description:

I'm trying to get the path of a network drive in PowerShell. With `Get-PSDrive` I get all the information I need.

```bsh
PS X:\> Get-PSDrive -Name X
```

```
Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                               CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                               ---------------
X                1527,59        214,61 FileSystem    \\Path\to\network\drive
```

Now I want to save Root in a variable, but when I do

```bsh
PS X:\> Get-PSDrive -Name X | Select-Object Root
```

I get

```
X:\
```

Why does Select-Object change the value? How can I get the "raw" value?

Comment: `Root` is actually X:\. You can see this with `Get-PSDrive -Name X | fl *`. You want the property `Select-Object DisplayRoot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default table display of `Get-PSDrive` displays the `DisplayRoot` property value  as `Root` unless it is empty. You can see this behavior by piping your `Get-PSDrive` to `Format-List *`. To control the output, you can use a calculated property with [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6).

```
Get-PSDrive -Name X | Select-Object @{
    Name='Root'
    Expression = {
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.DisplayRoot)) {
            $_.Root
        }
        else {
            $_.DisplayRoot
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

If you check the `$pshome\PowerShellCore.format.ps1xml` file, it defines the root value with the following expression, which is why you see this behavior.

```
if($_.DisplayRoot -ne $null) { $_.DisplayRoot } else { $_.Root }
```

Comment: Not strictly related, but do you actually know *why* it displays `DisplayRoot` as `Root`? I checked `types.ps1xml` but haven't found any explanation for that. And I'm not OP, just curious.

Comment: Yes. The PowerShellCore.format.ps1xml file at `$pshome` determines that.

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. I think this definitely violates the POLA, but that's for a Microsoft engineer to fix.